# How to get name of datatable column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTable 1.10.9 (from https://datatables.net). Columns for the datatable are defined at the initialization step in javascript and each column has a unique name, e.g.:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            columns: [
                { name: 'first-name' },
                { name: 'last-name' },
                { name: 'position' },
                { name: 'location' },
                { name: 'salary' }
            ]
        });
```

I know I can get the column from the table by the name I've given it, but I can't seem to find how to find a column's name from the column object. (I'm hoping it's possible with the current state of the component.) For example:

```
        table.columns().every(function() {
            //I'd want to see what the name of this column is, something like:
            console.log(this.name()); //will throw an exception since no such function exists
            //or
            console.log(this.name); //will output 'undefined'
        });
```

What's the proper function or property to get the name there?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can retrieve the initialization options through `table.settings().init()` - and by that the `columns` definition this way :

```
var columns = table.settings().init().columns;
```

When clicking on a cell / `<td>` you can find the column index by (best practice in case of hidden columns) :

```
var colIndex = table.cell(this).index().column;
```

An example of a click handler that alerts the corresponding `column.name` when a cell is clicked

```
$("#example").on('click', 'td', function() {
    //get the initialization options
    var columns = table.settings().init().columns;
    //get the index of the clicked cell
    var colIndex = table.cell(this).index().column;
    alert('you clicked on the column with the name '+columns[colIndex].name);
})
```

Your `every()` example would be

```
var columns = table.settings().init().columns;
table.columns().every(function(index) { 
    console.log(columns[index].name);
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6fstLmb6/**

Comment: Accepting this as the part with the every() would work for the example I've given in the question.

Comment: I can't be the only one who finds their api so backwards right?

Comment: I needed `table.settings().init().columnDefs` instead of `table.settings().init().columns`

Comment: You can get `colIndex` like the following now: `var colIndex = table.column(this).index();` Thanks for the rest.

Comment: Is there a solution without "init"? this causes trouble with fixed columns

Comment: @peace_love I am curius, what error? You can use `table.columns` instead -> https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns, hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

below code worked for me

```
this.api().columns().every(function() {
  console.log( this.header().textContent )
})
```

also you can add a specific html class for only specific column names like having that class

```
this.api().columns(".myColumnClass").every(function() {
  console.log( this.header().textContent )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you as per the [API document](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().every()#Type):

```
var tableColumns = [{
    name: 'first-name'
}, {
    name: 'last-name'
}, {
    name: 'position'
}, {
    name: 'location'
}, {
    name: 'salary'
}]

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    tableColumns
});

table.columns().every(function (index) {

    console.log(tableColumns[index].name);

});
```

Comment: That would probably work, but I'm hoping for a more DataTable-centric access solution - the class that is iterating through the columns only has DT object reference, it wouldn't have access to the tableColumns array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this another method. "*index*" variable is a column of your *thead*. This method will get the thead column of your table and read the text inside tag.

`dataTable.column(index).header().textContent`

Comment: Text content doesn't match the name though.

Answer (score -2):

[Documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) shows that [`columns().every()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().every()) sets `this` to the current column's [`column()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column()) object. Further examination of the column object shows that it has a [`column().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().data()) method which returns the data the column contains as an array of values. This should provide the data you need.

Comment: The op asked for a column name, not a data :)