# Get column names of rendered DT table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I took over a project that uses some tidy function to drop empty/ugly columns before rendering with `DT::renderDT()`. A cell value in a given column may represent another table and I would like to link to these. So if a user click a cell, the app should render another table of that name. However, cell values are only uniquely related to other tables in context of column names.`input$tbl_cell_clicked` only provides index and not column names. The tidying function may remove empty columns, so I cannot rely on index numbers.

How do I get the current rendered column names of the table?

```
  library(shiny)
  library(DT)
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12, DTOutput('tbl')))),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$tbl = renderDT(

        #I took over a project that uses some tidy functions to drop empty/ugly columns before rendering

        #column names and order therefore cannot be guranteed, here exemplified with use of sample()
        iris[,sample(ncol(iris),3)], options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
      )

      #i need to know the cell value and column name of latest click gesture, not only index col
      observe({

        #how can I retrieve the column name that cell clicked was in?
        print(input$tbl_cell_clicked)

        #The rendered table iris[,sample(ncol(iris))] cannot be scoped from here

        #Don't wanna go down that road of <<- solutions
        #could be solved by dumping latest iris[,sample(ncol(iris),3)] into a reactive values,
        #but that might look messy to use extra lines to save metadata from latest rendered DT


      })
    }
  )
```

Comment: Take a look at — https://stackoverflow.com/a/32605259/1457051 — but it means working with created javascript variables and getting that info back into R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a JavaScript solution.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

js <- c(
  "table.on('click', 'td', function(){",
  "  var cell = table.cell(this);",
  "  var colindex = cell.index().column;",
  "  var colname = table.column(colindex).header().innerText;",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('column_clicked', colname);",
  "});"
)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(column(12), verbatimTextOutput("colclicked")),
    fluidRow(column(12, DTOutput('tbl')))
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    output$tbl = renderDT(
      iris[,sample(ncol(iris),3)], options = list(lengthChange = FALSE), 
      callback = JS(js)
    )

    output$colclicked <- renderPrint({
      input[["column_clicked"]]
    })
  }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A reactive value reference could be inserted into tidy function. The tidy function dump info just before rendering to a reactive value containing column names latest rendered data.

```
#some tidy function mentioned several times many different place in code
a_tidy_function = function(
  dt, #df or dt
  #added this argument to tidy function
  reactiveRef=NULL) {
  #tidy data.frame / data.table
  tidy_dt = dt[,sample(ncol(dt))]

  #include this line to update reactive value at reactiveRef
  if(!is.null(reactiveRef)) reactiveRef(colnames(tidy_dt)) #

  return(tidy_dt)
}

  library(shiny)
  library(DT)
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12, DTOutput('tbl')))),
    server = function(input, output) {

      r_latest_column = reactiveVal()
      output$tbl = renderDT(

        #I took over a project that uses some tidy functions to drop empty/ugly columns before rendering

        #column names and order therefore cannot be guranteed, here exemplified with use of sample()
        {


        iris_rendered = a_tidy_function(
            iris,
            reactiveRef = r_latest_column) #col name info dumped to r_latest_column
        iris_rendered
        }, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)

      )

      #i need to know the cell value and column name of latest click gesture, not only index col
      observe({

        #here are the value and indexes
        print(input$tbl_cell_clicked)

        #and... column names are now accesible here...
        print(r_latest_column())


      })
    }
  )
```

As @hrbrmstr mentions in comment it is possible to retrieve column names from javascript domaine, I tried that and it seemed too cumbersome for what I have to complete today, however I found this promising tutorial I will look into...

https://github.com/FrissAnalytics/shinyJsTutorials
https://github.com/FrissAnalytics/shinyJsTutorials/tree/master/tutorials/materials3/messageApp2