# How to get columns names of jquery:datatable where the columns are created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a jquery:datatable in my code where its columns are created **dynamically** in the C# based on some table records in SQL.

In this datatable, I use a custom button called "Save". I need to get the column names of the table here as I get the data in the rows but I couldn't find the correct syntax to get the column names.

```
...
text: 'Save',
action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
          var json = JSON.stringify(dt.rows().data().toArray());
          // how to get the columns??
          // probably I need to use dt.columns().header() at some point?
        }
...
```

I believe I need to use `dt.columns().header()` as it gives me  tags with a lot of info, not sure how I can retrieve column name over there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like this might depend on the specific version of datatables (some use `.dataTable()` others `.DataTable()` - please let us know which version.   Here's an existing answer that does what you want for a specific version:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/32598279/2181514

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my own answer. Here it is:

```
var cols = ""

dt.columns().header().each(function (e, i) {
       var col = jQuery(e).html();
       cols += col + ",";
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the method

`table.columns().names();`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.